# udate a csv file using the other csv file in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have to update table1 using table2  ,append whole row from table2 to table1 if primary key of table1 is not present in table2 .If the primary key of table1 is present in table2 then all the columns of table1 are to be updated except the c3 of table1 with the values of table2.

table 1

```
c1     c2     c3
...   ....   ...
k1      a     e
k2      b     f
k3      c     g
k4      d     h
```

table 2

```
c1     c2     c3
...   ....   ...
k1      i      k
k5      j      l
```

required output

```
c1    c2     c3
...   ...    ...
k1      i     e
k2      b     f
k3      c     g
k4      d     h
k5      j     l
```

i tried the following code

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext}
 import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object Update {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("tabUP").setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

    val df1 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("f1.csv")
    val df2= sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("f2.csv")
    df1.registerTempTable("tab1")
    df2.registerTempTable("tab2")
    val df3=sqlContext.sql("UPDATE tab1,tab2 SET tab1.val2 = tab2.val1,tab1.val3 = tab2.val3 WHERE tab1.val1 = tab2.val1").show()


  }
}
```

Since data frames are immutable i am unable to do update on temp tables is there any way i can achieve it

Comment: why the result of k1 has i and e? isn't that supposed to be a and e?

Comment: table2 has updated data so table1 is to be updated with the data in table2. Only column c2 is to be updated not c3

Comment: I have answered below please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `outer join` the tables with `c1` column and copy the values of `table2` to `table1` as following. *Renaming* table2's columns of `c2` and `c3` as they have the same names as of table1.

```
val tempTable2 = table2.select('c1, 'c2.as("c22"), 'c3.as("c23"))

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
table1.join(tempTable2, Seq("c1"), "outer")
    .withColumn("c2", when('c22.isNotNull, 'c22).otherwise('c2))
    .withColumn("c3", when('c3.isNull, 'c23).otherwise('c3))
    .drop("c22", "c23")
```

You should have output as

```
+---+---+---+
|c1 |c2 |c3 |
+---+---+---+
|k2 |b  |f  |
|k4 |d  |h  |
|k5 |j  |l  |
|k1 |i  |e  |
|k3 |c  |g  |
+---+---+---+
```